# php dom removeChild error issue

Tags: php, dom, xhtml

I am getting an error on trying to remove nodes within xhtml.
The code is:

```
foreach($post->getElementsByTagName('a') as $key=>$a)
{
    $post->removeChild($a);
}
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found
>   Error'  in /var/www/content.php(24): content->fetch() #2 {main} thrown
>   in /var/www/content.php on line 192

If i use img tag instead, it removes all but one img nodes and no fatal errors.
What is going on here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try:

```
$a->parentNode->removeChild($a);
```

Comment: @sam can you add some of the xml and the code you're reading it with?

Answer (score 6):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a `DOMNodeList`. A `DOMNodeList` is late bound. E.g. if you change the document, you will also change the nodelist. So, if you plan on altering the document, you should read the nodelist into an array and then loop over the array instead. For reading operations, it will work exactly as an array, so here you'll be just fine.

So:

```
$nodes = array();
foreach ($post->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
  $nodes[] = $node;
}
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $post->removeChild($node);
}
```

Comment: read the nodelist into an array! foreach($post->getElementsByTagName('a') as $key=>$a){$atags[]=$a} and then loop over the $atags array. I tried it , but gives same error!

Comment: @troelskn @sam the problem is not that you're changing the document in the loop, but that `$post->getElementsByTagName` searches the whole node tree below `$post`. So using `$post->removeChild` is likly to give an error if the found `$node` is not a direct child of `$post`.

Comment: So if the a tag is wrapped in say a p tag, it will give this error?

Comment: @sam Yes, that's why I suggested the code above. Allways use the `parentNode`-property of a given node if you want to remove something.

Comment: The a tags are wrapped by b tags, so that could be it. Is there any way to search and delete nodes recursively cos the one above is not working.

Comment: @sam please show some of the xml you're using, the code above should work, so if it doesn't I'd guess there is something wrong/missing with the implementation.

Comment: @Yoshi let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1765/discussion-between-sam-and-yoshi)

Answer (score 2):

Ran into a similar issue, this is what worked for me to remove all elements of that tag from html the other answers caused errors. I was working with an HTML. Hope this helps someone. Must use a for statement because the node list and the DOM is dynamic.

```
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a')
for ($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++) {
                  $node = $nodes->item($i);
                  $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
                  $i--;
                }
```

Or a while statement:

```
while($nodes->length) {
                  $node = $FlavorNodes->item(0);
                  $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really address your problem, which I'm not too sure about, but it looks like you're trying to remove HTML tags from a post. Wouldn't the built-in function `strip_tags()` <sup>[***[docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)***]</sup> be better suited to this?

Comment: Yes i am trying to remove html tags, but not en masse, I am evaluating attributes and then remove tags selectively.

Answer (score -1):

```
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a'); // specify tag name you want to remove
$nodeToRemove = [];
foreach($nodes as $node) {
        $nodeToRemove[] = $node;
}
foreach ($nodeToRemove as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

Add check if you want to delete if blank tags only,

```
if (!$node->hasChildNodes() OR $node->nodeValue == '') 
{ 
  $nodeToRemove[] = $node; 
}
```